# How to create tree inside forloop php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakephp 3.6 and I have a modules tables in mysql database.

I want to create nested tree structure inside `foreach` loop. But i am not getting how to build loop in tree format.

Please help me to do so.

Below is my table strucure

```
id    parent_id  alias
119    NULL     Controllers
120    119      Clients
121    120       add
122    120       Edit
123    119      Users
124    123       add
125    123       Edit
```

**Expected Result**

```
Clients
 --add
 --Edit
 Users
 --add
 --Edit
```

**Below is my code**

```
<?php if(!empty($modulelist)) { foreach ($modulelist as $name){  ?>
    <li class="last dd-item">
            <input type="checkbox" name="short" id="short">
            <label for="short" class="custom-unchecked">Clients</label>     
        <ul>
             <li class="dd-handle">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="short-1" id="short-1">
                 <label for="short-1" class="custom-unchecked">add</label>
             </li>
             <li class="dd-handle">
                 <input type="checkbox" name="short-2" id="short-2">
                 <label for="short-2" class="custom-unchecked">edit</label>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use ORM behaviors Tree.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html

Based on Parent ID it will automatically generate TREE.

Comment: Yes its working correctly but i need to pass hardcoded id in for like
$descendants = $categories->find('children', ['for' => 119])->find('threaded')->toArray();
What if i dont need to pass 119 in for bcoz i have lots of data in table and it may be changing if i upload this on server,then ??

Comment: You mean first or base node you have to pass into tree ? right ?